# SharePoint OM wont' read item property

Tags: permissions, column, splistitem, spfield, field-controls

I have a list item with one field `Classes` which is a multiple choice lookup. I want to implement an ASPX page which contains a ListBox which is filled with values from the `Classes` field. The following method does that:

```
private void GetSelectedClasses()
{
    SPFieldLookupValueCollection currentSelection;

    using (SPWeb web = this.Web)
    {
        ClassesListBox.Items.Clear();

        currentSelection = item["Classes"] as SPFieldLookupValueCollection;
        foreach (SPFieldLookupValue value in currentSelection)
        {
            ClassesListBox.Items.Add(value.LookupValue);
        }
    }
}
```

This method works fine if I run/debug/deploy it with my account which is a SharePoint admin. However, when I run it under `User1` account, which has contribute permissions on the site and the list which contains the list item, I get the strange error:

> System.ArgumentException: Value does not fall within the expected range.

The error is happening in the line
`currentSelection = item["Classes"] as SPFieldLookupValueCollection;`
When I promote the `User1` to Full Control permissions user or even site collection administrator, I am still getting the error. The `ArgumentException` appears to be firing because the field named `Classes` doesn't exist, allegedly. This is of course not true, because checking the item fields does list it and it all works well with my default account.

Could anyone help me out? I feel quite desperate. Thanks!

Comment: I've also noticed that the same exception is thrown for all fields that are not of type text. This is really really weird.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I've solved it. I am not sure why, but when I use `User1` account, I need to explicitly specify the fields I want to get when I am retrieving `SPItem` object. So, previously I have had instantiated the `item` object with the following line:

```
this.item = this.list.Items.GetItemById(Convert.ToInt32(itemId, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture));
```

But, in order to have my `Classes` field included in the query, I need to use:

```
this.item = this.list.GetItemByIdSelectedFields(Convert.ToInt32(itemId, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture), "Classes");
```

My `GetSelectedClasses()` method mentioned in the question body is actually correct.